# How to align DIV within Window

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

http://jsfiddle.net/ApS9L

I have this DIV which I am trying to align with the other two divs. In the fiddle, you can see there is the border of 'our data center' and 'our other services', which align with each other in a 960 width frame (works great when resizing). However, I can't get the 'every account includes' to stay aligned with the two other sections below, and it stretches across, far beyond 960px.

Can you help me get the top div to align with the other two divs. 
Here is an image of live to show you my issues (there is a another column but it was breaking the fiddle). The colums are all grid_4 so grid_4*3 = 12, which shouldn't be causing issues..
[image: img]

Here is FULL HTML, please look on fiddle for CSS

```
<div id="hostingservices" class="grid_12">
            <div id="insidehostingservices" class="grid_12margin">
            <div class="constrain">
                <h1 class="bigtitle">Every Account Includes</h1>
                <div class="grid_4 alpha">

                    <h2>Email Features</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>UNLIMITED 1GB eMail Inboxes</li>
                        <li>POP3, IMAP & SMTP Access</li>
                        <li>Autoresponders & Mailing Lists</li>
                        <li>Email Forwarding, Catch All & Spam filtering</li>
                        <li>Junk Mail Filters</li> 
                     </ul>

                    <h2>Website Statistics</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Error & Access/Referrer/Agent Logs</li>
                        <li>Website Statistics</li>
                        <li>Google Sitemaps Generator</li>
                        <li>Webalizer Graphical Statistics</li>
                        <li>AWStats Graphical Statistics</li>
                        <li>Advanced Graphical & Text Counters</li>
                        <li>Bandwidth Statistics</li>
                        <li>Tracewatch</li> 
                    </ul>

                    <h2>Access Features</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Master & Additional FTP Accounts</li>
                        <li>SSH Access</li> 
                    </ul>

                    <h2>Databases</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>MySQL 5 Databases</li>
                        <li>MySQL Web GUI</li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- end of insideourdataservices grid9 alpha-->

                <div class="grid_4">
                    <h2>Advanced Features</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>eXtend Based Control Panel</li>
                            <li>Sub Domains</li>
                            <li>Microsoft FrontPage Extensions</li>
                            <li>Online File Manager</li>
                            <li>Website Redirection</li>
                            <li>Website submission to Google</li>
                            <li>Advanced Website Password Protection</li>
                            <li>Scheduled Tasks</li>
                            <li>IP Adress Blocking</li>
                        </ul>

                    <h2>Programming</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>PHP 4, PHP5 with SOAP Support</li>
                            <li>Perl, Python, Miva, RealAudio</li>
                            <li>Sun ONE ASP (Chilisoft ASP)</li>
                            <li>Ruby, Rails, ImageMagick, Ghostscript</li>
                            <li>Zend Optimizer, GD</li>
                        </ul>

                    <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Shared Secure Server Access (https)</li>
                            <li>osCommerce, Zen, CubeCart, Agora</li>
                            <li>Lots of Free Webtools inc Clipart</li>
                            <li>Google Adwords</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="grid_4 omega">
                    <h2>One Click Installations</h2>
                    <ul>

                        <li>Joomla 1.5</li>
                        <li>Wordpress Blog, Drupal</li>
                        <li>phpBB3 Discussion Forums</li>
                        <li>Elgg Social Networking System</li>
                        <li>CMS Made Simple, Guestbook, Geeklog</li>
                        <li>Nucleus Blog, Eblah Online Discussion</li>
                        <li>Typo3 CMS, Crafty syntax Live help</li>
                        <li>dot Project Management System</li>
                        <li>osTicket Ticeting helpdesk system</li>
                        <li>Form to Email with CAPTCHA</li>
                        <li>Custom 404 and 500 Error Pages</li>
                        <li>Online Auction (just like ebay!)</li>
                        <li>Online Photo Album</li>
                        <li>Web Calendar</li>
                        <li>Web Survey</li>
                        <li>Internet Countdown, Random Text Displayer</li>
                        <li>Random Images Displayer</li>
                        <li>Round Cube Webmail, MediaWiki</li>
                        <li> SugarCRM</li>
                        <li>Many Javascript Generators</li> 
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <a href="http://dchost.co.uk/basket" id="button3" class="ordernow">Order Now</a>
                </div>
            `</div> <!-- end of insideourdataservices grid12 margin-->
        </div> <!-- end of ourdataservicesimage grid3 omega-->

        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- clears ourdataservices grid12-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove min-width from the below style

```
#hostingservices {
    height: 800px;
    /* min-width: 1500px; */
    background: #F2F7FA;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, another set of eyes is what we need. Thank you this worked wonderfully! I can't believe I didn't spot it, could do with a break! (I will accept soon as 10mins passed)